# [ubuntu 18.04 a briefly showed screen right after log-in

Tags: themes, login-screen

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop and managed to customize themes for various components.

Not saying it's bad but there are so many purple screens coming up all along the booting process.

Grub, Splash, log-in - I was successful changing the color into something I like. Here's the problem. I see there is a purple screen briefly showing up right after logging in, literally in a split second.

I tried to recreate the condition by logging out and logging in again. It seems the screen only appears when I freshly boot or reboot.

If I ever know what the screen is called I could have googled it but I have no idea it is or what to search for.